# Control Asus Rog Strix g15 laptop fan speed in ubuntu

Tags: server, 22.04, fan, fancontrol

I've recently installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 and I can't controll the fan speed  using the asus-nb-wmi, it's not working.

I've tried manually changing the throttle_thermal_policy to 0, 1 and 2 and saving the file and with the bashrc alias scripts I found on another post, but nothing works...

EDIT: I've also tries with 2 programs one to monitor temperatures and another one to control fan speed but the second one is not detecting any fan.